# How to undo a "git add --all" that added all of the directories on my computer to git

Tags: git

Recently the command "git add --all" has been updated to add all the directories on my computer to git, I accidentally ran the command and now all of my directories have git on them. I wouldn't mind until I realized that my commits from one directory are being added to the log in the directory I accidentally ran the git commit. I am sure I can edit some git file to fix it but am unsure which one and I don't want to un-init commits in other directories, any ideas? Thanks.

Edit: Without just editing each .git in each directory on my computer.

Comment: Have you checked `git reset`? http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

Comment: `git add` refuses to run in a directory that isn't already a git repository. It does not create a repository with `.git` file. No git command creates multiple `.git` repositories across a file system tree. You seem to be making this up.

Comment: If you accidentally `git init` in the root directory of your computer's filesystem, all you have to do is remove the `.git` directory which it created.

Comment: not making this up, just don't remember the exact command I ran that did a git init, sorry new to this :/ ...
I ran a `rm -rf .git` at the top level and that seemed to work however, thanks

Comment: I made the same mistake. Stupid me.... Thanks to your question and wise people's answers, I was able to recover. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, found out that if you go to the top directory and run `rm -rf .git` it works